# Two definitions for non-singular in codimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, definition

I am trying to understand how the following definitions are the same.

**Shafarevich definition** (pg 128) -
A variety is *non-singular in codimension one* if the singular locus has codimension $> 1$.

**Hartshorne definition** (pg 130) -
A scheme is *non-singular in codimension one* if every local ring $\mathcal{O}_x$ of dimension one is regular.

My question is how to prove **Hartshorne** $\implies$ **Shafarevich**.

I guess that if $X$ is an affine variety and $Sing(X)$ has an irreducible component $Y$ of codimension one, then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of the corresponding prime $\mathfrak{p}$ should be non-regular. Is this true? If so where can I find the proof?

Comment: I think that you just proved it in the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't know how to prove the last statement.

Comment: I edited it, hopefully now it is clearer what I am stuck on.